# How can I debug degrading performance for my Shamu device?

Tags: usb-debugging, performance, 7.0-nougat, debug

I've had my Nexus 6 since it first came out and will be replacing it with the new Pixel anyway but I want to get to the bottom of this.

In the last 6+ months the phone got increasingly slow and unresponsive at times. Especially when using the camera but not only then. Battery life remained constant so I don't think there's something using all the CPU. Another symptom was that when having the Android 7 beta installed and being in low signal areas, it would restart randomly but that could've been just the `beta` part of Android 7.

I've noticed that factory resetting the phone or installing a new version of Android (such as Android 7) improve performance for a while after which it degrades again.

I've tried connecting the phone to `adb` but haven't noticed anything suspect in the logs. But then again I'm not an Android developer so I'm not sure what should I be looking for.

So my question was: is there any tool or procedure by which I can monitor the device and identify the cause of the issue?

Comment: Have noticed the slow-down after installing a particular app?  Could be some app that is misbehaving and causing high CPU and memory usage.  For Camera slowness, do you have lots of photos and videos on the internal storage?  Try backing them up somewhere (to your PC or cloud storage like Google Photos) and then deleting them off the phone.

Comment: Haven't noticed it being related to a particular app. I've tried pruning unnecessary apps as well.

I was more interested in methods of debugging and finding out the precise cause.

Comment: If there were a simple procedure to debug problems like this, they would be fixed before the software shipped!

Comment: I never said it would be easy, I just need more info on app usage, system resources, etc in order to pinpoint the problem. Not being familiar with the Android ecosystem I was asking for help in this regard.